# What is the best design practice to view multiple clocks that are generated from a single PLL within an FPGA?

Tags: fpga, pll, vlsi, virtex-series-fpga, metastability

Assume we have two clocks of 100 mhz and 200 mhz both generated from a PLL within an FPGA. If they are seen as two independent clock domains, then everything should work fine in the design, but there will be added complexity due to async fifo's or other metastability prevention techniques. If they are seen as belonging to a single clock domain, then l guess  we will have to do deskewing by adusting the phase offset within the PLL which according to my experience will be troublesome due to the required post-route simulation, and which is near to impossible for big designs ( unless you are willing to wait for the long simulation time). So I'm just curious as what is the best design practice in such a case. Also if the obtained clocks are not a multiple of 2^n, say 50 mhz and 150 mhz, then what solutions are used in practice. I appreciate your kind answers.

Comment: If the fast clock is an integer multiple of the slow clock, then a really smart move is to do away with the slow clock, route the fast clock everywhere, and use clock enables within the previous slow clock area so that it only updates every 2nd or 3rd fast clock. You use slightly more power for the wider fast clock distribution (if it is wider that is) and no more power in the 'slow' area, because the outputs are only changing at their slow rate. Otherwise, if you must have multiple real clock domains, restrict the signals crossing between so you can FIFO them properly.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with treating the two clocks as being synchronous if (a) both are generated from the **same** VCO clock, and (b) one is an integer multiple of the other. As long as your timing constraints treat them as such, the synthesis tools will usually work out the necessary skew to add.